# Cauchy Euler Equations and Substition

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm solving Cauchy Euler equations using substitution.  I'm absolutely perplexed as to why, when computing the second derivative, we get $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dt}t)=\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}\frac{dt}{dx}t$...  More specifically, as I understand it, the problem reads 'the derivative of the derivative of y with respects to t with respects to x.'  Given this, why exactly does this result in a $\frac{dt}{dx}$?

[image: fun!]

I sort of see it (we can't differentiate y w.r.t because y hasn't been defined yet w.r.t, so we use $y(t)=t$ where $t=e^{x}$), but if anybody can provide it, I need mathematical reasoning.  Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "by abuse of notation". What is happening is that one defines a new function $u(x)=y(e^x)$. Then the derivatives of $u$ follow from the derivatives of $y$, so that
\begin{align}
u'(x)&=y'(e^x)e^x&&=y(t)t
\\
u''(x)&=y''(e^x)(e^{x})^2+y'(e^x)e^x&&=y''(t)t^2+y'(t)t
\end{align}
In the book formulation, $t$ is at the same time independent variable and function of $x$ and $y$ denotes both $y(t)$ and the composite $y(e^x)$.

As one can see above, one can cut the confusion in half just by using another letter to denote the composite function.